# i trying to call this API address but didn't display

Tags: javascript, ajax

```
var xbtc = new XMLHttpRequest();
xbtc.open('GET', 'https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getmarketsummary?market=btc-xem', true);
xbtc.onreadystatechange = function(){
  if(xbtc.readyState == 4){
    var ticker = JSON.parse(xbtc.responseText);
    pc = market.Last;
    console.log(pc);
  }
};
```

Comment: it's a [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) problem - debugging tip: browsers have developer tools console (reachable usually by F12 on your keyboard) - errors in that console can help debug your code

Comment: note: I edited your TRIPLE SPACED code for you

Comment: @JaromandaX thank you..but here is no error..that is no  error

Comment: right, so you aren't seeing anything about CORS in the console?

Comment: oh, wait ... you have no `xbtc.send()` - so you haven't actually made the request at all - once you do, then you can forget doing this, because CORS will stop you

Comment: i try to display a data using console..but didn't display...

Comment: if the code you posted is your full code, then you don't know how to use XMLHttpRequest ... I already told you, you need to add `xbtc.send()` after the code you've shown, otherwise the request is **never made**

Comment: yes ...you right.here is an error...

Comment: XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getmarketsummary?market=btc-xem. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://127.0.0.1:3000' is therefore not allowed access.
VM868:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at XMLHttpRequest.bit.onreadystatechange (app.js:319)
bit.onreadystatechange @ app.js:319
XMLHttpRequest.send (async)
(anonymous) @ app.js:326

Comment: yep, and it's due to [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) as I said in the first comment 38 minutes ago

Comment: how to make header for it?..

Comment: first, you need access to the source for `https://bittrex.com/`

Comment: are you able to modify the code for that site?